# CodeIgniter 404 error log when no visible issue present

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

I have CodeIgniter configured to store errors. Every time I refresh a page I get a new message in my logs `ERROR on 2017-08-04 00:07:59 with message: 404 Page Not Found: Framework_assets/css`. The page loads correctly with no errors (visible).

Both folders are valid, I'm not receiving any 404 errors in dev console (all css files are loading correctly).

I access all my scripts in my view like so:
`<link href="<?php echo ASSETS_DIR; ?>/css/fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet">`
where `define('ASSETS_DIR', '/framework_assets');`

I found this: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-65040.html but it really doesn't answer my question. For example, why am I only getting a not found for the css when I do the same to get my js files? `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ASSETS_DIR; ?>/js/messaging.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

After hours I found this line at the end of my css:

`/*# sourceMappingURL=toolkit-inverse.css.map */`

Deleted it (the file didn't exist) and no more logs.